# How to use a file in the project to compare a temporary file while testing with pytest in GitHub?

Tags: python, github, pytest

I am trying to write tests with pytest.

I have a function "anonymize" which takes a directory path containing 6 .json files and updates them. Details of this function is not necessary to be explained.

I have 6 test .json files in the "./tests/my-test-data" directory, and
I have 6 other .json files in the "./tests/my-expected-results/" directory.

After giving the directory path "./tests/my-test-data" to the anonymize function, I am expecting for 6 .json files in "./tests/my-test-data" directory to be equal to the files in the "./tests/my-expected-results/" directory.

What I am doing is this, I am creating a temporary directory and copying my test data files in that directory. I am applying the function to that temporary directory.

My problem is: When I run the test with "python -m pytest", the tests pass. However, when I push the code to GitHub, they do not.

Here is what I am getting from GitHub:

[GitHub error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGQI8.png)

```
import filecmp
import os
import shutil

import pytest
from datacleaning.anonymize import anonymize


def test_Anonymize(tmpdir):
    directoryPath = "./tests/my-test-data"

    """
    Create a copy of the test directory and copy every file in that directory 
        into the copy directory
    """

    p = tmpdir.mkdir("sub")

    shutil.copy(os.path.join(directoryPath, "0_git.json"), p)
    shutil.copy(os.path.join(directoryPath, "0_jira_ratis.json"), p)
    shutil.copy(os.path.join(directoryPath, "1_github-pr_ratis.json"), p)
    shutil.copy(os.path.join(directoryPath, "2_git.json"), p)
    shutil.copy(os.path.join(directoryPath, "2_jira_ratis.json"), p)
    shutil.copy(os.path.join(directoryPath, "3_github-pr_ratis.json"), p)

    anonymize(p)

    assert filecmp.cmp(os.path.join(p, "0_git.json"),
                       "./tests/my-expected-results/0_git.json")
    assert filecmp.cmp(os.path.join(p, "0_jira_ratis.json"),
                       "./tests/my-expected-results/0_jira_ratis.json")
    assert filecmp.cmp(os.path.join(p, "1_github-pr_ratis.json"),
                       "./tests/my-expected-results/1_github-pr_ratis.json")
    assert filecmp.cmp(os.path.join(p, "2_git.json"),
                       "./tests/my-expected-results/2_git.json")
    assert filecmp.cmp(os.path.join(p, "2_jira_ratis.json"),
                       "./tests/my-expected-results/2_jira_ratis.json")
    assert filecmp.cmp(os.path.join(p, "3_github-pr_ratis.json"),
                       "./tests/my-expected-results/3_github-pr_ratis.json")
```

What is the reason that the same test passes in my code editor, and it does not in GitHub and how to fix it?

Comment: Rights? Do you have access to create the tempdir? Have you tried using 'with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as dirpath' https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryDirectory